# http 401 error when providing an access token the outlook api

Tags: javascript, http, post, microsoft-graph-api, token

I am trying to create a folder for a user, and I have been unsuccessful with api call attempts. My code is able to receive the correct access token, so I believe the be bug would be in createFolderTestFunction below.

[image]

```
async function redirectToDashboard() {
  console.log("redirect to dashboard");
  // var response = await requestTokenSilent();
  var response;
  if (!response || !response.status == 200) {
    response = await requestTokenPopup();
  }

  if (response.accessToken) {
    console.log(response);
    createFolderTest(response.accessToken);
    // location.href = hostname;
  } else {
    console.log("Unable to acquire token");
  }
}


function createFolderTest(accessToken) {
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: accessToken,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    mode: "cors",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      displayName: "@COOLMONDAY"
    })
  };

  var graphEndpoint = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/Inbox/";

  fetch(graphEndpoint, options)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: 401 is not a javascript error, as you write in the title, but an HTTP error meaning the request is not authorized. I guess there's an issue with the accessToken. Unfortunately, in your screenshot, we don't see inside `headers` property...

Comment: @Pierre The headers are the same as what is written in the code. I understood it is not a javascript error. I just wanted to add javascript to the title for so experts in javascript would help.

Comment: you have to dig into API reference, maybe there are other headers or parameters needed. The API is clearer, you are not authorized. I don't see where you tell the API which operation you want (creating a folder). Maybe you have forgotten that in the body. Maybe your app is not allowed to perform some operations ; I don't know MS API, but in Google API, you have read or read/write access. Could it be something like that ?

Comment: It says I am not authorize, but you can see I have receive an access token. So that cannot be the reason. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#create-folders says I need a mail.readwrite privileges, but I see this in the scope of the response body. So it cannot be I did not get the correct privileges.

Comment: @RahmiPruitt "Experts in JavaScript" are not necessarily experts in REST APIs. Since you have not even posted the content of the response in the XHR requesting the access token, having an expert in JavaScript will not be of any help here. As Pierre mentioned this is clearly an authentication issue. Either your are not passing the correct access token to the code OR **your access token does not have the scope required to perform the operation**.  Please pay attention with your tags as it could get your question closed.

Comment: @NoahBoegli thank you for the feedback. I will post a picture of the scopes granted to me.

Comment: your graphEndpoint is wrong, according to the reference you pasted above... You are missing "childfolders" at the end. Next time, please read carefully before posting here ; I already pointed out that you were missing the "action" thing, never indicating the desired operation

Comment: @Pierre that is not correct. I tried that at first but it did not work. I saw someone else had it like above in their github so tried that. I did my research and read the documentation ;).

Comment: @Pierre I add a new picture in case you do not believe me.

Answer (score 0):

A recommendation would be to get this working in Graph Explorer first. As this eliminates any issues with language being used and access token permissions.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview

The Microsoft Graph endpoint is actually https://graph.microsoft.com/ , you can use the outlook url but moving forward Graph is where we invest in documentation, sdks and tooling.

As per the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You should be using, you're missing 'mailfolders'

```
POST /me/mailFolders
```

You could also use our JavaScript SDK which makes mistakes like these a little easier with intellisense and strongly typed objects.

```
    const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const mailFolder = {
  displayName: "displayName-value"
};

let res = await client.api('/me/mailFolders')
    .post(mailFolder);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript